# Translating 0 row and 0 column in image to real world orientation C#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, gdi+

I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to translate 0 row and 0 column positions in an image to an actual real world description of an image's orientation. I'm reading orientation image data using GDI+. Retrieving the orientation value is not the problem; however, figuring out what the heck these values really mean is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534416(v=vs.85).aspx#_gdiplus_constant_propertytagorientation

Microsoft's article above pretty much tells you which corner of the image is the 0 point. I can't seem to find any other article which explains exactly what these 0 points mean.

*"1 - The 0th row is at the top of the visual image, and the 0th column is the visual left side. 2 - The 0th row is at the visual top of the image, and the 0th column is the visual right side. 3 - The 0th row is at the visual bottom of the image, and the 0th column is the visual right side. 4 - The 0th row is at the visual bottom of the image, and the 0th column is the visual left side. 5 - The 0th row is the visual left side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual top. 6 - The 0th row is the visual right side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual top. 7 - The 0th row is the visual right side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual bottom. 8 - The 0th row is the visual left side of the image, and the 0th column is the visual bottom."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read that, orientation = 1 is standard (x, y) co-ordinates with (0,0) at the top left

orientation = 2 means that the image has been flipped around the vertical axis so that (0, 0) is now the top right

orientation = 5 means that the image has been rotated 90 degrees clockwise so that (0, 0) is the top right again, but the rows are now vertical

etc etc